# Converting between const struct types in compile time

Tags: c, struct, unions, compile-time

Given a constant struct in one API, which is to be interpreted as 16 consecutive uint8_t bytes in other API, is there a method in C to make this conversion in compile time:

What I'd like to achieve is something like

```
 const union {
     struct a {
         uint32_t a;
         uint16_t b;
         uint16_t c;
         uint8_t d[8];
     } a;
     uint8_t b[16];
 } foo = { .a = { 0x12341243, 0x9898, 0x4554,
                { 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08 } } };

struct from_other_api manifest = {
    .appuuid = foo.b;
    // { foo.b[0], foo.b[1], ...  }
};
```

This approach, as well the second version in the commented line unfortunately give both an error *error: initializer element is not constant*, even though this surely *looks* like a constant.

The business reason is that both the definitions `struct from_other_api manifest` and the constant memory blob come an API, which is not to be modified. The conversion can be done manually as

```
struct from_other_api manifest = {
    .appuuid = { 0x43, 0x12, 0x34, 0x12, 0x98, 0x98, 0x54, 0x45,
                 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08 }
};
```

but is to be avoided, as this is a regular pattern yelling to be automatized.

Comment: are you using `C99` or above?

Comment: I'm using gcc without specifying `-std=c99`; even though it may look like it, it can be a gnu extension as well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C constant variables cannot be used in constant expressions.

If you can initialize `manifest` at runtime, you can do it with `memcpy` as in Snaipes answer.

But if `manifest` must be initialized at compile time, you may need to (ab)use preprocessor. It won't be too pretty, but it works:

```
#define ID 0x12341243, 0x9898, 0x4554, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08

#define FOO(nnn)  { .a = FOO2(nnn) }
#define FOO2(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k) \
    { a, b, c, { d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k } }

#define MAN(nnn) MAN2(nnn)
#define MAN2(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k) \
    { a >> 0 & 0xFF, a >> 8 & 0xFF, a >> 16 & 0xFF, a >> 24 & 0xFF, \
    b >> 0 & 0xFF, b >> 8 & 0xFF, \
    c >> 0 & 0xFF, c >> 8 & 0xFF, \
    d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k }

const union {
    ...
 } foo = FOO(ID);

struct from_other_api manifest = {
    .appuuid =  MAN(ID)
};
```

Comment: It's pretty enough. Given that the first sentence is true and constant variables can't be used in constant expression, then it's macro magic time.

Answer (score 2):

This declaration does not declare a variable.

```
struct a {
     uint32_t a;
     uint16_t b;
     uint16_t c;
     uint8_t d[8];
 };
```

To declare a variable named `a` with the same structure inside the `union`, use this:

```
const union {
    struct {
         uint32_t a;
         uint16_t b;
         uint16_t c;
         uint8_t d[8];
     } a; // now a is accessible with a.a, a.b, a.c and a.d[i].
     uint8_t b[16];
} foo = { .a = { 0x12341243, 0x9898, 0x4554,
            { 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08 } } };
```

Comment: True, I'll edit the question, since it contains a copy-paste error.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot pass anything other than literals in array initializers.
Use `memcpy(3)` instead:

```
struct from_other_api manifest = {
    // initialize other members
};
memcpy(manifest.appuuid, foo.b, sizeof (manifest.appuuid));
```